# converting a simple maven project to a spring boot project from maven

Tags: maven, spring-boot

use eclipse,I new a maven project.
After,I replace pom to the spring boot pom and create counter java file.
But when I run this application,it went error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yao.service.PersonInfoRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 31 more
```

I think this maybe coused by some config,but I don't know what config to.

**Supplement:** When I Generate the demo project from [here](http://start.spring.io/), the same code is run normal.

This is my main class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.yao" })
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StartApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to replace the pom?? Does your `PersonInfoRepository` have a `@Component` (or sub annotations like `@Repository) annotation?

Comment: The sample Maven pom is Lacking some dependencies,like, ‘<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>’ . Yes,My    PersonInfoRepository have not a _@Component_ annotion. But ,When I add this annotation,there always have the error.